# Store Particular Column name as key and Column data as values in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list Col_values and Data Frame df.

```
Col_values = ['a','d']

df 
    a       b        c       d      e
1   apple   bat      cat     dance  eat
2   air     ball     can     dog    ear
3   ant     biscuit  camel   doll   enter
4   alpha   batch    came    disc   end
5   axis    bag      come    dell   
6   angry            catch
7   attack
```

My expected output is OutDict

```
OutDict={'a' : ['apple','air','ant','alpha','axis','angry','attack'],
         'd':['dance','dog','doll','disc','dell']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions if no values are missing values first create list for both filtered columns and then remove missing values in dict and list comprehension, here is used `np.nan != np.nan`:

```
d = {k: [x for x in v if x == x] for k, v in df[Col_values].to_dict('l').items()}
```

Or processin each column separately and remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
d = {c: df[c].dropna().tolist() for c in Col_values}
print (d)
{'a': ['apple', 'air', 'ant', 'alpha', 'axis', 'angry', 'attack'],
 'd': ['dance', 'dog', 'doll', 'disc', 'dell']}
```

---

If no values are empty strings:

```
d = {k: [x for x in v if x != ''] for k, v in df[Col_values].to_dict('l').items()}
```

Or:

```
d = {c: df.loc[df[c].ne(''), c].tolist() for c in Col_values}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jezrael for editing the question and providing solution as well.

Comment: Hi @Jezrael. I had made few changes to the question can you help me with this.

Comment: @GnaneshwarBabu - Can you create new question?

Comment: Sure. @Jezrael
https://stackoverflow.com/q/57850988/9929272 This is link for the new question.