# Store Particular Column name as key and Column data as values in dictionary. I need the mapping to be occur irrespective of the Case and plurality

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list Col_values and Data Frame df.

Col_values = ['App','dragons']

df

```
    apps       b        c     dragon      e
1   apple     bat      cat     dance     eat
2   air       ball     can     dog       ear
3   ant       biscuit  camel   doll      enter
4   alpha     batch    came    disc      end
5   axis      bag      come    dell   
6   angry              catch
7   attack
```

My expected output is OutDict

```
OutDict={'App' : ['apple','air','ant','alpha','axis','angry','attack'],
         'dragons':['dance','dog','doll','disc','dell']}
```

I need the mapping to be occur irrespective of the Case and plurality.

Thanks in Advance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[:,['apps','dragon']].to_dict(orient='list')
```

**Output**

```
{'apps': ['apple', 'air', 'ant', 'alpha', 'axis', 'angry', 'attack'],
 'dragon': ['dance', 'dog', 'doll', 'disc', 'dell', 'None', 'None']}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{col:df[col].tolist() for col in df.loc[:,['age','fare']].columns}
```